# get ResultSet into JTxtField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, resultset

i want to get my full resultset to display into my JTxtField, but i dotn know how to do it.

**This is my code At the moment:**

```
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn3 =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ARTURO-LAPTOP;user=sa;password=sacompusis;database=PDV");
        st3 = conn3.createStatement();
        rs3= st3.executeQuery("SELECT Nombre_Pdv, SUM(Total) AS Expr1 FROM   VENTA_PLATILLOS GROUP BY Nombre_Pdv");

        while(rs3.next()){
            txt.setText(rs3.getString(1));
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However this only gives me the first string of the resultset, how can i get the full result set?

Comment: JTextField doesn't support multiple lines. You may want to look at JTextArea.

Comment: Did you try method toString

Comment: @A.Sharma you are right but he can get all result in one line of the text

Comment: i tryed a jtextArea but stil the .getString(1) only gives me the first result not the full result set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while loop may be setting many Strings to the JTextField, but only one will show -- the last one set as the JTextField's text, since it will over-write all text added before.

If you must show all Strings in the JTextField, then create a StringBuilder object, and within the while loop, *append* the ResultSet text you get into the StringBuilder, and then after the while loop, use the `toString()` from the StringBuilder as the text for the JTextField. e.g.,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(rs3.next()){
    sb.append(rs3.getString(1) +"; ");
}
txt.setText(sb.toString());
```

Better: display the text in a JTextArea, appending it in the while loop with `"\n"`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(rs3.next()){
    sb.append(rs3.getString(1) +"\n");
}
myTextArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Even better still: display the whole ResultSet data in a JTable by creating a TableModel, either derived from AbstractTableModel for flexibility or DefaultTableModel for ease, and adding rows from the ResultSet into the model using your while loop, and then setting a JTable's TableModel with this created and filled model.

Comment: i tryed your jtextArea method, but the getSting(1) only gets me the first result of my resultset not the full result how can i get the full resultset?

Comment: @ArturoMartinez: Then your current resultset might only hold one row, or hold all rows hold the same data. You'd best do some debugging either with a debugger or with println statements to find out.